# Version conflict when Gradle pull dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jersey

In my project, jersey-core is pull from many dependencies. I don't know from which ones. I believed it doesn't matter because I thought that if multiples dependencies pull the same one, than gradle would always take the higher version. I was wrong.

```
[ERROR] [main] [n/a] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:94) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
```

AnnotationScannerListener is 1.19, ReflectionHelper is 1.1, and the method getContextClassLoaderPA() does not exist in ReflectionHelper 1.1

How can I force gradle to always take the higher version?

I use intellij.

Comment: Not sure of the proper syntax, but typically you'd do something like this by excluding the transitive dependency manually. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default gradle should add the highest version of a dependency to the classpath.

You can force the version of a dependency to be a specific version like so:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {

    // force certain versions of dependencies (including transitive)
    //  *append new forced modules:
    force 'asm:asm-all:3.3.1', 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
  }
}
```

This example was lifted directly from https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html, which might be worth a read, along with https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Another piece of advice, if you want to find out what is pulling in conflicting versions of jars, you can do the following:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency $dependencyName --configuration $configurationName
```

where `$dependencyName` should be substituted for the name of your dependency (such as `asm-all`), and `$configurationName` should be replaced with the configuration name you wish to check for (such as `compile`). This will give you a graph of what versions are being pulled in by which dependencies.

Comment: 'force' was enough, didn't need 'forcedModules'. Thx.